# Algoritmo e complexidades

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo

Se construir um algoritmo com complexidade de pior caso teta de n^2 posso ter como contrapartida uma complexidade de melhor caso para esse algoritmo com big O n^2?

Answer (score 3):

Sim. Mas eu usaria uma notação diferente para falar do melhor caso.

Quando escrevemos que o pior caso é `O(f)` queremos dizer que o tempo gasto no pior caso é assintóticamente menor ou igual a essa função. Mas o "menor ou igual" não serve pra se discutir sobre melhor caso.

O que queremos na verdade é uma notação que signifique "maior ou igual". A notação convencional pra isso é o `Ω(f)` (big-omega).

Voltando à pergunta original: se o pior caso é `O(n^2)`, o melhor caso pode, sim, ser `Ω(n^2)`. Basta que o seu algorítmo seja um cujo tempo de execução dependa apenas do tamanho da entrada, mas não de seu valor específico.

Comment: A complexidade de pior caso do algoritmo da questão é teta de n^2 (ele já tem um limite superior assintoticamente justo), não é big O de n^2. Quero saber se no algoritmo em questão a complexidade de melhor caso pode ser big O de n^2.

Comment: Pode sim. Pegue o caso do quicksort: o pior caso é Θ(n^2) e o melhor caso é Θ(n log n)

Comment: Desculpe mais vou insistir. Vc mostrou um caso em que tenho um algoritmo em que o pior caso é teta de n^2 mas o melhor caso não é big O do mesmo n^2 e sim de (nlogn).

Comment: @MarcosAntonio E quanto ao algoritmo da seleção ([*selection sort*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort))? Ele executa o mesmo número de passos não importa se a lista está ordenada, se não está, nem há qualquer caso particular que o faça executar mais rápido ou mais lento. Ou seja, ele é O(n^2) e Ω(n^2) - e portanto Θ(n^2) - tanto no melhor caso quanto no pior.